# Grails application design

Tags: grails

In Grails application i have EmploymentSeeker domain as below :

```
class EmploymentSeeker {
    String fullName
    String expYears
    Boolean haveDrivingLic
    String gender
    String eduQualification
    String courses
    String currentTitle
    int age
}
```

I want to make the user in the **create view** to add previous references. user may add up to 4 references , but I don't know how to do it - shall I create **Emp references domain** and link it to employment seeker domain `static belongsTo`?

Comment: yes... what kind of answer did you expect?

Comment: @injecteer so how i would allow the user to add multiple references

Comment: create an instance of your reference class, set it's employee property.

Comment: @injecteer this is from the controller side (save action) , what about from the view side (create.gsp) ?

Comment: @Sherif use scaffold and check autogenerated code for a view.